# Remove column taking last column as reference

Tags: awk, sed

I am looking to remove third last and second last column and print the rest using bash. eg.

```
Line 1 ------ A B C D E F G H I J K
Line 2 ------ A B C D E F E F I G H I J M
Line 3 ------ A B C D E I J Y
Line 4 ------ A B C D A B C D F G J E F G H I J C
```

Now taking last column as reference ($NF) I need to remove third last and second last column.

Desired output should look like below where in each line I J should be removed.

```
Line 1 ------ A B C D E F G H  K
Line 2 ------ A B C D E F E F I G H  M
Line 3 ------ A B C D E Y
Line 4 ------ A B C D A B C D F G J E F G H C
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending if you want to keep or collapse the separators around the removed fields:

```
$ awk '{$(NF-2)=$(NF-1)=""}1' file
Line 1 ------ A B C D E F G H   K
Line 2 ------ A B C D E F E F I G H   M
Line 3 ------ A B C D E   Y
Line 4 ------ A B C D A B C D F G J E F G H   C

$ awk '{$(NF-2)=$(NF-1)=""; $0=$0; $1=$1}1' file
Line 1 ------ A B C D E F G H K
Line 2 ------ A B C D E F E F I G H M
Line 3 ------ A B C D E Y
Line 4 ------ A B C D A B C D F G J E F G H C
```

You said in a comment about `...retains my tab delimiter`. If your fields are tab-separated then state that in your question and add `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` at the start of the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `for` loop inside of awk:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){if (i<NF-2||i==NF){printf i==NF?"%s\n":"%s ", $i}}}'
```

That's just looping through all of the columns, if the column isn't the 2nd or 3rd from last then it prints the column, appending a line feed if it's the last column.

There may be a prettier way to do it in awk, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(\s+\S+){3}$/\1/' file
```

Replace the last 3 fields with the last field on each line.